# I have written excel code for 2010 Office (64 bit) with visual studio express c#, how to run it on 2010 office (32 bit)?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have written an excel code for my computer (Windows 7, Excel 2010 64 bit version).
It works fine.

I wanted to test it on a 32 pc. (Windos XP 32 bit, Excel 2010 32 bit version).

As expected it didn't work when it tries to communicate with excel.

How I can overcome this problem and make my code also run in 32 bit excel?

Thank you.

Comment: What framework did you use for your project? Since you are using the VS Express version I doubt it's a VSTO addin, what sort of project are you talking about? A class library?

Answer (score 0):

Change your project's `Platform Target` to `Any CPU` also i would recommend not to use Office Interop assemblies, Then your application will depend on office version whereas you could use open source libraries which is compatible with any office version. [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) is good example which supports office 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013.

Comment: In Visual Studio Express the default setting for Build Tab the Platform Option is set to "Active(Any CPU)". And there appears nothing else than it. When I run is on 32 bit machine, the form is loading well. But when I click one button to interact with excel, an error rises. So I thing there is an issue with Excel 32 bit and 64 bit files. (dlls, interop assemblies or whatever else)

Comment: @macrobook If you want to test the functionality on a 32bit environment then you will need to use 32bit excel interop.